# How do I replace default JSSOR images?

Tags: javascript, css, jssor

I'm trying to use my own images with this logo bar slider - could someone point out where the images are being pulled from in the JSSOR code? And how I could insert my own? Thank you very much. Link to javascript below:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxAFLV4mheqqUEJldHJaR0N0amc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following code, and replace image urls with your own.

```
<div><img u="image" alt="amazon" src="../img/logo/amazon.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="bitly" src="../img/logo/bitly.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="blogger" src="../img/logo/blogger.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="dnn" src="../img/logo/dnn.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="drupal" src="../img/logo/drupal.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="ebay" src="../img/logo/ebay.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="facebook" src="../img/logo/facebook.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="google" src="../img/logo/google.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="ibm" src="../img/logo/ibm.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="ios" src="../img/logo/ios.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="joomla" src="../img/logo/joomla.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="linkedin" src="../img/logo/linkedin.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="mac" src="../img/logo/mac.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="magento" src="../img/logo/magento.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="pinterest" src="../img/logo/pinterest.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="samsung" src="../img/logo/samsung.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="twitter" src="../img/logo/twitter.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="windows" src="../img/logo/windows.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="wordpress" src="../img/logo/wordpress.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" alt="youtube" src="../img/logo/youtube.jpg" /></div>
```